# typedef a struct without preventing the keyword struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Suppose this scheme:

```
/* avl.c */

typedef struct avl {
    void *data;
    int height;
    struct avl *left, *right;
} node;

/* avl.h */

struct avl; /* opaque */
```

I want to use:

```
struct node *root;
```

instead of

```
node *root;
```

in avl.c, but for now the best I have found is:

```
struct avl {
    void *data;
    int height;
    struct avl *left, *right;
};

#define node avl
```

Another way?

Comment: What (higher level) problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no other way than using macros to do that. The reason is that struct tags have their own *namespace*. Different names in the tag namespace always refer to different types, even if the structs contain the same member types. Proper aliasing of types can only be done with typedefs, which are *defined* to be aliases and not separate types.

Answer (score 3):

Then you should remove the `typedef`:

```
struct node{
    void *data;
    int height;
    struct node *left, *right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want to refer to struct node as <struct node> in avl.c and as <struct avl> in the rest of the project

Comment: I don't understand why would You want to use a struct type with two different name, but your `#define` will do it.

Answer (score 3):

Without using the preprocessor, you must give the struct and the typedef the same name for that to work, e.g.

```
  typedef struct node {
        void *data;
        int height;
        struct node *left, *right;
    } node;
```

So now `struct node` and `node` is the same thing.

Comment: Right, but now I want an opaque struct called `struct avl` (not simply `avl`) to be an alias

Comment: @DavidRF Which means you'll need to do some preprocessor shenanigans.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct avl {
    void *data;
    int height;
    struct avl *left, *right;
};

typedef struct alv node;

struct avl* ptr1; //valid
avl* ptr1; //not valid
struct node* ptr2;  //valid
node* ptr3;  //also valid
```

That forces you to use `struct avl`, that doesn't force you to use `struct node`, but you can if you want to.

Comment: Thanks @zakinster, but doesn't seems to work outside of avl.c using an opaque struct